# Encrypt an audio file with AES and XTR-DH Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, aes, crypto++

I've done write code for encrypt an audio file with WAV format with AES CFB mode and XTR-DH for generate secret key.

The code here

```
int main()
{
AutoSeededRandomPool aSRPA;
XTR_DH xtrA(aSRPA, 170, 160);

string inputfilename;
string encryptfilename;
int aesKeyLength = SHA256::DIGESTSIZE;
int defBlockSize = AES::BLOCKSIZE;
const std::string extention(".wav");

byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
aSRPA.GenerateBlock(iv, AES::BLOCKSIZE);
SecByteBlock privateA(xtrA.PrivateKeyLength());
SecByteBlock publicA(xtrA.PublicKeyLength());
SecByteBlock secretKeyA(xtrA.AgreedValueLength());
xtrA.GenerateKeyPair(aSRPA, privateA, publicA);

SecByteBlock key(SHA256::DIGESTSIZE);
SHA256().CalculateDigest(key, secretKeyA, secretKeyA.size());

cout << "file path plain text : ";
cin >> inputfilename;
cout << "file path cipher text : ";
cin >> encryptfilename;

        if (inputfilename != extention &&
            encryptfilename != extention &&
            inputfilename.size() > extention.size() &&
            encryptfilename.size() > extention.size() &&
            inputfilename.substr(inputfilename.size() - extention.size()) == 
            ".wav" &&
            encryptfilename.substr(encryptfilename.size() - 
            extention.size()) == ".wav")
        {


            CFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption cfbEncryption(key, aesKeyLength, iv);
            cfbEncryption.ProcessData((byte*)inputfilename.c_str(), 
                                      (byte*)inputfilename.c_str(), 
                                      inputfilename.length() + 1);


            FileSink file_kunci(encryptfilename.c_str());
            StringSource ss(inputfilename, true,
                new StreamTransformationFilter(cfbEncryption,
                    new Redirector(file_kunci)));
         }
}
```

It's work but when I read the encrypted file, it's not a wave form like an audio file. What's wrong with my code ? Is it need to convert the audio file to array of byte or something ?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do, and what your data is. I see AES encryption, and not XTR encryption. `StringSource ss(inputfilename, ...)` appears to encrypt the filename; and not the data in the file. I think you need a `FileSource fs(inputfilename, ...)` (but I could be wrong). It is also kind of unusual to mix a `BlockCipher::ProcessData` with a pipeline. You can use two sequential pipelines and pump to the same sink. The pipeline will append to the sink `file_kunci` (and not overwrite it).

Comment: After your edit, this looks unusual: `xtrA.GenerateKeyPair(aSRPA, privateA, publicA);`. I think you should switch to either [DLIES](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Discrete_Logarithm_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) or [ECIES](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). Both are integrated encryption schemes, and both are based on the Diffie-Hellman problem. DLIES is over the field of integers, and ECIES is over the field of elliptic curves. Otherwise DLIES and ECIES are roughly the same.

Comment: @jww I just tried to combine because I dunno how to encrypt with XTR-DH. I have been using StreamTransformationFilter and for save encrypted audio and always appear message to break the operation

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you actually want as your question title and code differ, therefore I'm going to take your code as reference. To me it looks like you want to encrypt a file and decrypt it later.

Your big if block is really too much... you can do everything pretty easiely with [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Also you seem to be mixing things up, this can happen if you are not familiar with cipher algorithms and/or the documentation of the library itself. First you `ProcessData` which seems to encrypt the string in `inputfilename` (?).

After all, you might want to take a look into the documentation of the library and the provided samples - these already help you a lot to understand how things are handled.

Here's a working self-contained sample of encryption and decryption of a file.

```
#include <filesystem>

#include "..\CryptoLib\osrng.h"
#include "..\CryptoLib\modes.h"
#include "..\CryptoLib\files.h"
#include "..\CryptoLib\aes.h"

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t FixedArraySize(T(&arr)[N])
{ return N; }

int wmain(int argv, wchar_t **args)
{
    try
    {
        using namespace CryptoPP;

        constexpr CryptoPP::byte    IV[]    = { 0xab,0x10,0x55,0x29,0x73,0xb9,0xae,0xba,0xe9,0xe9,0xe5,0x26,0x35,0x66,0x63,0x55 };
        constexpr char              key[]   = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";

        const std::string extension         = ".TEST";
        const std::string sourceFile        = __FILE__;
        const std::string destinationFile   = std::filesystem::path("Encrypted").replace_extension(extension).string();
        const std::string finalFile         = std::filesystem::path("Decrypted").replace_extension(extension).string();

        {
            CFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryption(reinterpret_cast<const CryptoPP::byte*>(key), FixedArraySize(key) - 1, IV);
            FileSource fsEnc(sourceFile.c_str(), true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryption, new FileSink(destinationFile.c_str())));

            CFB_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption(reinterpret_cast<const CryptoPP::byte*>(key), FixedArraySize(key) - 1, IV);
            FileSource fsDec(destinationFile.c_str(), true, new StreamTransformationFilter(decryption, new FileSink(finalFile.c_str())));
        }

        std::filesystem::remove(destinationFile);
        std::filesystem::remove(finalFile);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```